# how can I do a Windows file search by file owner

Tags: filesystems, search, windows-search, ownership

I want to find a particular Excel file created by a past employee. All I know for sure is the file format (Excel 1997-2003) and the file owner's name. How can I search for this file on a Windows network share by file owner?

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: My own pc is XP 2002 SP3 but I can run the search from the fileserver (Windows Server 2003)

Comment: Se this...http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/28798-file-search-ownership.html

Comment: Thanks Moab. +1. SubInACL it is. Now how can I close this question?

Comment: Moab - add this as an answer if you wish

Answer (score 11):

```
DIR C:\*.* /S /Q|FIND /i "username" > C:\userlist.txt
```

the above searches for every thing the user had in the `C:` drive, you can substitute the drive letter and the file extention. ex: `C:\*.xls` or `P:\*.xls`. the result is sent to `C:\userlist.txt`, you can direct it to any path of your desire.

Comment: The output does not contain the file path for each file owned by the particular user. What combination of switches would you use to include this information?

Comment: Info on [DIR](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755121%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) & [FIND](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725655(v=ws.11).aspx) (surprisingly easy to follow) in case people want to do a few more advanced operations

Answer (score 4):

If you don't really like command prompt (I wouldn't blame you) then simply type "owner:" It should change color as soon as you type the colon. The owner is not a person's name, but rather their user name. You can get a feel for the format, in case you use something strange, by adding the "owner" column in a normal file view.

To do that, right click at the top of detail view in a file explore window (Win+E, if you like shortcuts) and choose "More..." then add owner. Note: you have to right click on an existing column. It's sort of an oversight on microsoft's part. So if all you have is the normal Name, date, type, size, and folder, you can't right click to the right of the folder column.

That's a handy trick to find out who messed with your latest excel file. It'll show you whoever saved it last.

As an example, I wanted to find all Adobe Illustrator files that I made inside of a particular folder. I first go to that location then type:
owner:myusername *.ai (where .ai is the file extension for adobe illustrator documents)
This search shows me all of the illustrator files where I was the last person to save.